# JetBrains WebStorm drag reference to html

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have enabled editor setting "Enable Drag n Drop Functionality". And I want to select a css file from project window and drag into index.html file like this: `<link href="app/app.css"/>`

But when I drag and drop to index html file not working. It opens file in a new tab.

Comment: Your IDE version? It woks for me. And .. as far as I'm aware that setting does not have anything to do with this functionality.

Comment: version is webstorm 11.0.4

Answer (score 1):

Such feature was added just recently and is available since **WebStorm 2016.2** only (sort of v13).

2016.2 version is not out yet (in EAP stage at the moment -- Early Access Program) but you can try latest EAP build right now if so desired.

You can read more about this feature as well as get the link for EAP build here: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/05/webstorm-2016-2-eap-162-232/